# Where can I find reference to this remark in Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

[image: p.286 in Algebraic Geometry]

It says that for a additive functor $T:Mod(A)\to Mod(A)$, if $T$ is left exact and commutes with direct sums, then there exists an $A$-module $Q$ such that $T=\mathrm{Hom}_A(Q,-)$.

I want to see a proof of this, a constructive proof better.

Comment: This looks like the Brown Representability Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown%27s_representability_theorem) (which is stated for contravariant functors; I'm not sure if there's a covariant version).

Comment: The claim is not correct. There are similar statements that are true (and can be proved by an adjoint functor theorem) but this seems to be a garbled mixture that is false as stated.

Comment: @ZhenLin Can you post the correct statement or a reference to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim closely resembles some known facts but is not correct.
Perhaps one of these is what Hartshorne meant:

**Theorem 1.**
If $T : \textbf{Mod} (A) \to \textbf{Ab}$ preserves small limits and $\kappa$-filtered colimits for some regular cardinal $\kappa$, then $T \cong \textrm{Hom}_A (Q, -)$ for some $\kappa$-presentable $A$-module $Q$.

*Proof.*
$\textbf{Mod} (A)$ and $\textbf{Ab}$ are locally finitely presentable categories, so under the hypotheses $T$ has a left adjoint, say $F : \textbf{Ab} \to \textbf{Mod} (A)$, and $F$ preserves $\kappa$-presentable objects.
In particular, $Q = F (\mathbb{Z})$ is $\kappa$-presentable, and
$$T (M) \cong \textrm{Hom}_\mathbb{Z} (\mathbb{Z}, T (M)) \cong \textrm{Hom}_A (F (\mathbb{Z}), M)$$
hence $T \cong \textrm{Hom}_A (Q, -)$.　◼

**Theorem 2.**
If $S : \textbf{Mod} (A)^\textrm{op} \to \textbf{Ab}$ sends small colimits in $\textbf{Mod} (A)$ to limits in $\textbf{Ab}$, then $S \cong \textrm{Hom}_A (-, R)$ for some $A$-module $R$.

*Proof.*
$\textbf{Mod} (A)$ is a locally finitely presentable category, so under the hypotheses $S$ has a left adjoint, say $G : \textbf{Ab} \to \textbf{Mod} (A)^\textrm{op}$.
Let $R = G (\mathbb{Z})$.
Then,
$$S (M) \cong \textrm{Hom}_\mathbb{Z} (\mathbb{Z}, S (M)) \cong \textrm{Hom}_A (M, G (\mathbb{Z}))$$
so $S \cong \textrm{Hom}_A (-, R)$.　◼

If we want to consider endofunctors on $\textbf{Mod} (A)$, we need to be a bit more careful.

**Theorem 3.**
If $T : \textbf{Mod} (A) \to \textbf{Mod} (A)$ *is $A$-linear* and preserves small limits and $\kappa$-filtered colimits for some regular cardinal $\kappa$, then $T \cong \textrm{Hom}_A (Q, -)$ for some $\kappa$-presentable $A$-module $Q$.

*Proof.*
Same as theorem 1, except that we need to know that the left adjoint $F : \textbf{Mod} (A) \to \textbf{Mod} (A)$ obtained is also $A$-linear.　◼

**Theorem 4.**
If $S : \textbf{Mod} (A)^\textrm{op} \to \textbf{Mod} (A)$ *is $A$-linear* and sends colimits in $\textbf{Mod} (A)$ to limits in $\textbf{Mod} (A)$, then $S \cong \textrm{Hom}_A (-, R)$ for some $A$-module $R$.

*Proof.*
Same as theorem 2, except that we need to know that the left adjoint $G : \textbf{Mod} (A) \to \textbf{Mod} (A)^\textrm{op}$ obtained is also $A$-linear.　◼

We also have the Eilenberg–Watts theorem:

**Theorem 5.**
If $L : \textbf{Mod} (A) \to \textbf{Mod} (B)$ preserves small colimits, then there is a $(B, A)$-bimodule $C$ such that $L \cong  C \otimes_A (-)$.